# moving objects in python on its own

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make an object(a ship) to move on its own with its own speed and random direction,  but after looking at the internet, I could only find objects that are moved manually. I tried using randrange to maybe make it move randomly

```
    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
        self.player_sprite.center_x = random.randrange(800)
        self.player_sprite.center_y = random.randrange(800)
```

but it needs multiple clicks and my ship just jumped around. Could someone teach me how to do it properly? thank you.

After trying to implement the recommendation from below i came up with this:

```
    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
    while self.score != 1:
        while button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
            self.player_sprite.center_x += random.choice([-1, 1])
            self.player_sprite.center_y += random.choice([-1, 1])
        if self.score == 1:
            break
    print("box has been found!")
```

but now the program would not run at all and gives an exit code of -805306369.

Comment: Allowing user control, but letting the computer decide their movement... Hmm, interesting game. Would like more details on what you're trying to accomplish. This does not give us enough to help you.

Comment: if you want random movement, what is the significant of `button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:`

Comment: @Jaba,im trying to make a ship that moves around the board randomly until it collides with a black box. the problem is, i have no clue as to making the ship move by itself.

Comment: @GaurangShah, I tried that because i thought that it would start to move randomly when i click my mouse. which resulted in teleporting my ship randomly instead of moving it slowly...

Answer (score 1):

To move your ship smoothly, you need to move it one step at a time.

`random.randrange(800)` will give you random value from 0 to 800 and that's why your ship is jumping.

What you need is something like this.

```
 if button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
        self.player_sprite.center_x += random.randrange(-1,2)
        self.player_sprite.center_y += random.randrange(-1,2)
```

**random.randrange(-1,2)** will give you either -1, 0 or 1 value.

- Adding that to **x axis** it will either move **left**, **right** or won't move at all.
- For **y axis** it will either move **up**, **down** or won't move.

In case if you alway want to move. You can change `random.randrange(-1,2)` to `random.choice([-1, 1])`

Comment: I see, I tried implementing the code and I need to be rapidly clicking my mouse for it to move. Im guessing it has something to do with the 'button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:' statement. What should I change it into for it to move by itself? @GaurangShah

Comment: just write `infine loop` the only thing you need to take care of wall (border) and what you want to do when ship reaches there.

Comment: Okay, will try it out. Thank you.